# Hide/Show top bar on mouse move and show when video on pause

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

i am working on a video player and on that video player i have a div called #caption, when i play the video i hide the div and when i pause the video i show the div. This all works fine. Now i added a small part of javascript that shows the div when i move the mouse and hides the div again if i stop moving the mouse with a timeout. This works fine as well. However, if i pause the video and i move the mouse the #caption also hides with the time out. How do i prevent this piece of javascript to fire when the player is in pause, so the #caption is always visible when the video is paused.

```
var video = $('#thevideo')[0];

video.addEventListener('pause', function () {
$('#caption').show();
})

video.addEventListener('playing', function () {
$('#caption').delay(2500).fadeOut();
})

var i = null;
$("#videoContainer").mousemove(function () {
        clearTimeout(i);
        $("#caption").fadeIn();

        i = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#caption").fadeOut();
        }, 2500);
 })

 <video src="iamavideo.mp4" id="thevideo"></video>
 <div id="caption">hi there!</div>
```

Comment: you'll want to only set the timeout if the video is playing

Comment: yes, i tried adding it inside the video.addEventListener 'Playing' but that however still fires the timeout section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your example to add in the #videoContainer, and put the elements above the script so they're found.

Added code to cancel the #caption fadeout timer if it's been set when the video pause button is pressed.

Added a test to the mousemove to only start the fadeout if the video is playing (not paused).

```
<div id="videoContainer">
    <video controls muted src="BigBuck.mp4" id="thevideo"></video>
    <div id="caption">hi there!</div>
</div>

<script>

var video = $('#thevideo')[0];
var i = null;

video.addEventListener('pause', function () {
    $('#caption').show();
    // video has paused, so if the caption fadeout timer has started, cancel it
    clearTimeout(i);
})

video.addEventListener('playing', function () {
    $('#caption').delay(2500).fadeOut();    
})


$("#videoContainer").mousemove(function () {
    clearTimeout(i);
    // only start the timer if the video is not paused
    if (!video.paused) {
        $("#caption").fadeIn();

        i = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#caption").fadeOut();
        }, 2500);
    }
})

</script>
```